# Input to reshape is a tensor with 20736 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 160

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using https://github.com/XifengGuo/CapsNet-Keras code to generate capsnet model. When i want to use the manipulate latent feature the error came up. I am using rgb image with dimension 28x28px, 20 epoch and 20 batch size. i tried to modify the number but the error still show up. Here is the error.

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 20736 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 160
     [[node model_25/primarycap_reshape/Reshape (defined at <ipython-input-14-c8ff7dc492cd>:34) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_17210]
```

And here is the code.

```
def manipulate_latent(model, data, args):
    print('-' * 30 + 'Begin: manipulate' + '-' * 30)
    x_test, y_test = data
    index = np.argmax(y_test, 1) == 3
    number = np.random.randint(low=0, high=sum(index) - 1)
    x, y = x_test[index][number], y_test[index][number]
    x, y = np.expand_dims(x, 0), np.expand_dims(y, 0)
    noise = np.zeros([1, 4, 16])
    x_recons = []
    for dim in range(16):
        for r in [-0.25, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25]:
            tmp = np.copy(noise)
            tmp[:, :, dim] = r
            x_recon = model.predict([x, y, tmp],batch_size=20)
            x_recons.append(x_recon)

    x_recons = np.concatenate(x_recons)

    img = combine_images(x_recons, height=16)
    image = img * 255
    Image.fromarray(image.astype(np.uint8)).save(args.save_dir + '/manipulate-%d.png' % args.digit)
    print('manipulated result saved to %s/manipulate-%d.png' % (args.save_dir, args.digit))
    print('-' * 30 + 'End: manipulate' + '-' * 30)
    

def PrimaryCap(inputs, dim_capsule, n_channels, kernel_size, strides, padding):
    output = layers.Conv2D(filters=dim_capsule*n_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=strides, padding=padding,
                           name='primarycap_conv2d')(inputs)
    outputs = layers.Reshape(target_shape=[-1, dim_capsule], name='primarycap_reshape')(output)
    return layers.Lambda(squash, name='primarycap_squash')(outputs)

# def PrimaryCap(inputs, dim_capsule, n_channels, kernel_size, strides, padding):
#     outputs = []
#     for _ in range(n_channels):
#         output = layers.Conv2D(filters=dim_capsule, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=strides, padding=padding)(inputs)
#         outputs.append(layers.Reshape([output.get_shape().as_list()[1] ** 2, dim_capsule])(output))
#     outputs = layers.Concatenate(axis=1)(outputs)
#     return layers.Lambda(squash)(outputs)
    
def CapsNet(input_shape, n_class, routings, batch_size):
    x = layers.Input(shape=input_shape, batch_size=batch_size)
    
    # Layer 1: Just a conventional Conv2D layer
    conv1 = layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=9, strides=1, padding='valid', activation='relu', name='conv1')(x)

    # Layer 2: Conv2D layer with `squash` activation, then reshape to [None, num_capsule, dim_capsule]
    primarycaps = PrimaryCap(conv1, dim_capsule=8, n_channels=32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='valid')

    # Layer 3: Capsule layer. Routing algorithm works here.
    digitcaps = CapsuleLayer(num_capsule=n_class, dim_capsule=16, routings=routings, name='digitcaps')(primarycaps)

    # Layer 4: This is an auxiliary layer to replace each capsule with its length. Just to match the true label's shape.
    # If using tensorflow, this will not be necessary. :)
    out_caps = Length(name='capsnet')(digitcaps)

    # Decoder network.
    y = layers.Input(shape=(n_class,))
    masked_by_y = Mask()([digitcaps, y])  # The true label is used to mask the output of capsule layer. For training
    masked = Mask()(digitcaps)  # Mask using the capsule with maximal length. For prediction

    # Shared Decoder model in training and prediction
    decoder = models.Sequential(name='decoder')
    decoder.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_dim=16 * n_class))
    decoder.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    decoder.add(layers.Dense(np.prod(input_shape), activation='sigmoid'))
    decoder.add(layers.Reshape(target_shape=input_shape, name='out_recon'))

    # manipulate model
    noise = layers.Input(shape=(n_class, 16))
    noised_digitcaps = layers.Add()([digitcaps, noise])
    masked_noised_y = Mask()([noised_digitcaps, y])
    manipulate_model = models.Model([x, y, noise], decoder(masked_noised_y))
    return manipulate_model

manipulate_model = CapsNet(input_shape=x_train.shape[1:],
                          n_class=len(np.unique(np.argmax(y_train, 1))),
                          routings=args.routings,
                          batch_size=args.batch_size)

    
manipulate_latent(manipulate_model, (x_test, y_test), args)
```